# The Data Area passed through a System Call is Too Small

Tags: onedrive, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint site synced as a mapped drive and when I try to open a file from a file path that's over 260 characters, I get the error, 'The Data Area passed through a System Call is too Small.'

So I went through the registry and group policy and enabled long paths as well as updating Office, and my graphics card. Nothing seems to work.

Has anyone had any success in fixing this issue.

I have Ver 1903 and OS Build 18362 of W10 Pro.

Comment: See [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation). Try using path syntax like `\\?\D:\very long path`.

Comment: @HarryMC I've tried that but still no go. I've literally sent an entire day researching this and nothing seems to work.